# How can I plot a graph of an integral?

Tags: plotting

I want to plot the following function:

$$\int \left(\frac{\Gamma (x+1)}{2}-\frac{\Gamma (x-1)}{2}\right) \, dx$$

Comment: what are the limits of integration

Comment: @k_v I want to plot the indefinite integral of this function.

Comment: this integral may be calculated only numerically, and one of the limits of integration is requared to define the function

Comment: @k_v so how can I plot it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
g[x_]=Gamma[x+1]/2-Gamma[x-1]/2 // FunctionExpand
```

> (-(1/2) + 1/2 (-1 + x) x) Gamma[-1 + x]

```
f[y_] := NIntegrate[g[x], {x, 2, y}]

Plot[f[x], {x, 2, 10}]
```

[image]

Comment: Why NIntegrate does not work inside plot?

Comment: this works `Plot[NIntegrate[g[x], {x, 2, y}], {y, 2, 10}]`

Comment: I have tried before asking this question, it does not.

Comment: @Anixx I does work. What *Mathematica* version are you running?

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`NDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolveValue) to integrate the function:

```
int = NDSolveValue[
    {
    f'[x] == Gamma[x+1]/2-Gamma[x-1]/2,
    f[2] == 0
    },
    f,
    {x, 2, 10}
];
```

Visualization:

```
Plot[int[x], {x, 2, 10}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It may be interesting to plot both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ (blue and yellow curves, respectively) on a logarithmic scale:

```
LogPlot[{f[x],g[x]}, {x, 2, 30}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False]
```

[image]